# Any way to get rhansontable() to stretch rows vertically while data entering?

Tags: javascript, r, rhandsontable

Below, I'd like the first row to be stretched vertically, even while data-entering. Currently when data-entering, it becomes one long horizontal line. Would this be fixable with Javascript using a Custom Renderer as per [the page on rhandsontable](http://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/)?

```r
library(tibble)
library(rhandsontable)
library(stringr)
library(glue)
long_sentence <- rep(sentences[1], 10) |> glue_collapse()

DF = tibble(
  work_order = 1:5, 
  issue = c(long_sentence, sample(sentences, 4)),
  date = seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", length.out = 5),
)

rhandsontable(
  DF, 
  rowHeaders = NULL
) |> hot_cols(colWidths = c(100, 200))
#> Warning in as.character.POSIXt(as.POSIXlt(x), ...): as.character(td, ..) no
#> longer obeys a 'format' argument; use format(td, ..) ?
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>